# Json server is not a function

Tags: reactjs, json

When i run npm run dev in terminal , output this error

`failed to load config from C:\Users\Dell\MMS-Project\vite.config.js error when starting dev server: TypeError: jsonServer is not a function at file:///C:/Users/Dell/MMS-Project/vite.config.js.timestamp-1708935716148-24614b2a2fe3c.mjs:6:22 at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25).`

I used Vite for react project.

I reinstalled json server and checked vite.config.js file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.